Updating foreign keys MySQL
I currently am working on a web scraper that takes premier league data and imports it into a mySQL database, but I am having issues updating foreign keys in some of the tables. For some context, I have four tables in my database: teams - containing team name and a primary key teamID, seasons - containing the season years and a primary key seasonID, seasonstats - contains stats for each team in each season and uses foreign keys to reference the team and season IDs, and matches - contains match data from every match for each season, which also uses foreign keys to reference team and season IDs.
The tables are created as follows:
CREATE TABLE teams (
    teamID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    teamName VARCHAR(100),
    
    PRIMARY KEY (teamID)
);

CREATE TABLE seasons (
    seasonID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    season VARCHAR(10),
    
    PRIMARY KEY (seasonID)
);

CREATE TABLE matches (
    matchID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -- Match data including references to teamIDs and seasonID

    PRIMARY KEY(matchID),
    FOREIGN KEY(seasonID)
    REFERENCES seasons(seasonID),
    FOREIGN KEY(homeID)
    REFERENCES teams(teamID),
    FOREIGN KEY(awayID)
    REFERENCES teams(teamID)
);

CREATE TABLE seasonstats (
    statID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    season VARCHAR(10),
    seasonID INT,
    teamName VARCHAR(100),
    teamID INT,
    -- Other season stats

    PRIMARY KEY (statID),
    FOREIGN KEY (seasonID)
    REFERENCES seasons(seasonID),
    FOREIGN KEY (teamID)
    REFERENCES teams(teamID)
);

I first tried using insert statements in MySQL workbench after importing all the data, but this did not work.
Example insert: INSERT INTO seasonstats(teamID) VALUES ((SELECT teamID FROM teams WHERE teamName = seasonstats.teamName));
After this, I tried to add a column containing the foreign key values to the pandas dataframe before using the to_sql method on it. I was able to do this because I had each season and team stored in an array before loading them into the database. Therefore, I was able to determine the ID value for them by simply finding their index in the array and adding 1 (since my primary key values start at 1). However, after adding this column and running the program again, I was given the following error:
(mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError) 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (premdata.seasonstats, CONSTRAINT seasonstats_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (seasonID) REFERENCES seasons (seasonID))
So, I am wondering if there is either a way I can auto update the foreign keys upon insertion of data into the seasonstats or matches table, or if there is a way to update the constraints to allow me to insert my own values into the foreign key cells.

mysql can not auto update foriegn keys, you firsdt need to add row to  all tables that are referenced
